# Using & Setting Static Function Pointers in Different Classes

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

I have 2 classes, A and B

A has a function called foo();

B has a **static function pointer** designed to point towards foo, let's call it fuu.

The definition of fuu in class B looks like this

```
static void (A::*fuu)();
```

Somewhere along the runtime class A sets fuu.
The code I wrote resembles this

```
B::fuu = &A:foo;
```

This properly sets the function pointer, however I am unable to use it (I am calling it in the B class)

I've tried

```
*fuu();

 B::fuu();

 B::*fuu();
```

Is there a syntax error preventing me from dereferencing?

TLDR: Trying to call a non-static function from an instance of class A, from a static function in class B

Answer (score 3):

You need

```
(a.*fuu)();
```

where `a` is an object of class `A`, or

```
(aptr->*fuu)();
```

where `aptr` is a pointer of type `A*`.

You can't call a non-static member function of class `A` without an object of class `A` to call it on.

Comment: Is there a reason for being unable to call a non-static member function? I assumed that since the pointer pointed to the address space then I would be able to just call it after dereferencing.

Also would it be possible to work around this? Perhaps passing a non-static function into a static function as a callback?

Comment: The pointer to a non-static member function is like a pointer to a function that passes an object pointer as the first parameter (that will be accessible as 'this' within the function). To call a function pointer like this, you need to pass all parameters, including the first one - the ways shown in answer are basically syntatic sugar to fill that 1st parameter.